# What did St. Thomas Aquinas write about Christ's passion?

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, thomas-aquinas, passion-of-jesus

St. Thomas Aquinas never wrote a complete treatise devoted solely to Christ's passion. So what did St. Thomas Aquinas have to say about Christ's passion?

Comment: I'm sure he thought it was a good thing...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This contains a collection of excerpts from [St. Thomas's works](https://isidore.co/aquinas/) (e.g., his *Summa*, quodlibetal questions, and commentaries on the Gospels) that pertain to the passion:

## [*Meditations for Lent from St. Thomas Aquinas*](https://archive.org/details/meditationsforle00aquiuoft) ([audiobook](http://www.alleluiaaudiobooks.com/catholic-audiobook-st-thomas-aquinas-for-lent/))

Comment: When was it written? What was the context if not specifically about the Passion? Where could one get it in written or digital formats? Your answer is doing the minimum right now, and worse, is doing it obnoxiously.

Comment: I was under that impression that link only answers were not up to par on .SE sites.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast It's a reference-request question.

Comment: @Geremia Shrinking the giant link and  removing the misleading "audiobook" part would make it a decent answer. Though you still don't give any information directly. Even reference questions should have the question answered **here** without having to follow links. A link to where they can read it is nice,  but the question is not asking "where can I read it".